# Display the contents of two UI.XML in a single GWT Presenter

Tags: java, xml, gwt, uibinder, gwtp

I am using GWTP with UIbinder. MyPresenter.java is correctly representing the information on MyPresenter.ui.xml. However, I need to display in MyPresenter.java as well the contents of MyClass.ui.xml, whose values come from MyClass.java (not a presenter). Is there a way to do that?

**MyPresenter.ui.xml**

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
    ui:generateFormat='com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.format.PropertiesFormat'
    ui:generateKeys='com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.keygen.MD5KeyGenerator'
    ui:generateLocales='default' xmlns:p1="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client">
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <g:Label ui:field = "myDiagramsText" styleName="{res.style.mydiagramsLabel}"/>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

**MyClass.ui.xml**

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
        <g:HTMLPanel> <div ui:field='Panel'>HOLA HOLAHOLAHOLA</div> </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about GWTP. generally  In MVP pattern view and presenter have one to one relationships. but in mvc controller and view have one to many relationship.
in respect of design it is impossible to have two view for one presenter.

there are some work around:

1- you can create a composite view consist of these two view and one composite presenter

2- in large scale apps there is some flow controller that encapsulates flow of UI's. this controller gets events and update respective UI's.

this is usually what i did in my own application.